# "TypeError: Object of type 'float' has no len()" at clickhouse insert function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, insert, clickhouse

I have dataset to upload in clickhouse server. I use pandas to convert in dataframe, then i am inserting it by clickhouse_connect.insert() function. I created table in clickhouse server by clickhouse_connect.command() function. But i faced problem at inserting as error : Object of type 'float' has no len().

Actually the main problem was before i changed all columns datatypes to string(but they are not). I changed them cause i had error : Required argument is not integer.

So, when i tried to understand my error, i thought that main problem can be related to datatypes of dataframe columns and clickhouse server columns.

By the way i am not using any len() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please include the stack traces of your error.

In any case, you are almost certainly correct, the data in the Pandas DataFrame must have the same type, or be convertible to the same type, as the ClickHouse column you are trying to insert into.  If you change the data to a string and then try to insert into a ClickHouse Float or Int column, insertion will normally  fail.

You should debug your original error "required argument is not an integer".  If you can provide the stack trace of that error it should be possible to find your problem.

Comment: ohh god, i think i am blind,  i did not look to datatypes of my columns, i found that 42nd column is not matching datatypes